# Links in the Table of contents of a published (via embed) Google Doc do not work in Gooogle Sites

Tags: hyperlink, embed, google-docs, google-workspace, google-sites-2016

I have pages in our Google Site (within our Workspace account) which use embed to show published Google Docs containing Table of contents.
The links in the table of contents don't work! Links to external sites work.
If the Google Doc is published on the Google Site using link instead of embed the links in the table of contents work...
I've tried the same Google Doc in a separate Google Sites hosted on a consumer gmail account and the links in the table of contents work!!
Is there a setting in Workspace which prevents the table of contents links to work when using embed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Scenario 1: Within a Workspace account (both the Google Doc and Google Site belong to the same Workspace account
Links in the Google Docs Table of Contents (TOC) work perfectly OK (ie they link to the relevant paragraph) in the Google Doc. When I "Publish to the web" the Google Doc into a Google Site webpage (using Embed) , the same TOC links don't work: when you click on any one of the links in the TOC nothing happens!
Scenario 2: Same Google Doc published in a Google Site belonging to a consumer account: the links of the TOC in published document in Google Site (using embed) do work!